# Would cereal still group together if it were suspended in the liquid (milk) - rather than floating on top?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

According to my interpretation of several online sources (*correct me if I am wrong*), cereal tends to group together in our bowls of milk because it creates a deformation on the surface of the liquid which causes the other pieces of cereal to "flow downhill" so to speak.

I am attempting to take the surface of the liquid out of the equation, because I am wondering if other forces would still cause the cereal to group together. The best way I imagined doing so was if the cereal is suspended, rather than floating on top.

Not knowing how to actually do this test, and whether it would actually test what I'm trying too - I was hoping another person could enlighten me.

---

What forces would be acting on the suspended cereal - even if the forces are too weak to cause the cereal to actually move towards each other?

Would the cereal still group together if it were suspended in the liquid?

Comment: The floating version: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139607/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142111/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71292/2451 and links therein.